# Unable to parse Json in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I used to parse JSON to list of objects by the following way:

```
final response = await api(map);
var raw = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];
dataList = parseJson(raw["datalist"]);

List<dataRecord> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = convert.jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<dataRecord>((json) => dataRecord.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

and the JSON is in this format:

```
datalist: [{"id": 29737, "rent": 700, "unit": "A", .....
```

this works fine in all of my existing projects.

However, I am now retrieving data from an external source and the JSON is in this format:

```
data: [{id: 4109486, unicorn_id: 7836045, memorial_id: 23072601320076, ...
```

field labels and string values all without quotes, and I am not able to use the same `parseJson` function to parse the JSON.

Comment: Why are you receiving your JSON in the way you are receiving it? Maybe it is malformed?

Comment: Is an external source not controlled by ourself.  I know this json can be read by some websites, just don't know how it can be parsed in Flutter.

Comment: Try parsing it as YAML.  "relaxed JSON" which is what that looks like is a subset of YAML, so maybe they're using a YAML dump of their data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to add quotes around the keys and string values in the response.

```dart
String preprocessResponse(String responseBody) {
  final processedResponse = responseBody.replaceAllMapped(
    RegExp(r'(\w+):'),
    (match) => '"${match.group(1)}":',
  );

  return '{"datalist": [$processedResponse]}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to add a hook to the JSON parser.
First hook to parse `_keyValue`.
The second hook is to parse `_string`.

This allows you to parse regular JSON and JSON that uses identifiers as object keys.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/extra/json_parser.dart' as json_parser;
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/predicate.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/recognize.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/skip_while.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/skip_while1.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser_combinator.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/runtime.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/tracing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  const raw1 = '''
data: [{id: 4109486, unicorn_id: 7836045, memorial_id: 23072601320076}]
    ''';

  const raw2 = '''
"data": [{"id": 4109486, "unicorn_id": 7836045, "memorial_id": 23072601320076}]
    ''';

  const parser = JsonParser();
  final input1 = '{$raw1}';
  final r1 = parser.parse(input1);
  print(r1);

  final input2 = '{$raw2}';
  final r2 = parser.parse(input2);
  print(r2);
}

class JsonParser {
  static final _parser = _createParser();

  const JsonParser();

  Object? parse(String input) => parseString(_parser.parse, input);

  static Parser<String, Object?> _createParser() {
    const ident = Recognize2(SkipWhile1(_isIdentStart), SkipWhile(_isIdentEnd));

    var stringCount = 0;
    Result<O>? parse<O>(Parser<String, O> parser, State<String> state) {
      final name = parser.name;
      if (name == '_keyValue') {
        stringCount = 0;
      }

      final result = parser.parse(state);
      if (name == '_string') {
        stringCount++;
        if (result == null && stringCount == 1) {
          final result2 = ident.parse(state);
          if (result2 != null) {
            return result2 as Result<O>;
          }
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

    bool fastParse<O>(Parser<String, O> parser, State<String> state) {
      return parser.parse(state) != null;
    }

    final builder = TracerBuilder(
        fastParse: fastParse,
        parse: parse,
        filter: <O>(parser) {
          return parser.name == '_keyValue' || parser.name == '_string';
        });
    return builder.build(json_parser.parser);
  }

  static bool _isAllowedChar(int c) => c == 0x5f;

  static bool _isIdentEnd(int c) => _isIdentStart(c) || isDigit(c);

  static bool _isIdentStart(int c) => isAlpha(c) || _isAllowedChar(c);
}
```

Output:

```
{data: [{id: 4109486, unicorn_id: 7836045, memorial_id: 23072601320076}]}
{data: [{id: 4109486, unicorn_id: 7836045, memorial_id: 23072601320076}]}
```